# 2 Rigidbodies on top of one another

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a base rigidbody which is kinematic using rigidbody.position to move it in a forward direction. On top of this base I have another rigidbody using gravity sat on it. I'm trying to get the top one to stay on top of it and move with the base. The problem I'm having at the moment is that the top rigid body moves with the base however not at the same speed, it moves slower therefore eventually falling off. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add the component: fixed joint, so that it will be fixed, no matter which direction/speed you will go. Also, if you have any further problems with the way it works, look for the constrains in the rigidbody component.